# Is it possible to pull certain information from "Net User Query (Username) /dom" through powershell 5.1?

Tags: powershell

I'm taking calls at a Helpdesk, and I use PowerShell 5.1 (in restrained language mode with no access to additional modules), running "net user query (username) /dom" for every call.

I'm trying to create a script that makes this process easier and wanted to create a function with the result that I get, but am unsure how to.

How do I select a specific result that comes from the information once net user query command is completed? such as attribute "Full name" and "account log in status"? Is this possible without having any modules installed?

I was hoping to create a variable from the results of some of the information that is returned and then plug them in to other commands.

Comment: While it's much more comfortable to have the `ActiveDirectory` module available so you can do things like `Get-ADUser` directly, you can parse command output with some finagling. `ConvertFrom-String` comes in handy here, as in `$u = @{}; net user ... /domain | ConvertFrom-String -Delimiter '\s{2,}' -PropertyNames Name, Value | ForEach-Object { $u[$_.Name] = $_.Value }`, which then allows things like `$u.'Full name'`.

Comment: ^ Indeed, if OP doesn't have an allowance for the ActiveDirectory module, I would strongly suggest requesting the IT Security team there provide an allowance for it because the kind of work an IT helpdesk person would use PowerShell for really needs the ActiveDirectory module to be useful. Active Directory manipulation in some form or another is often like 50% of a helpdesk employee's workload.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thank you so so so much, this worked perfectly. I really appreciate you taking the time to reply.  THANK YOU!!!! And yes Tyler I agree, I've proposed it to my team leader but he isn't keen on the idea unfortunately. Hopefully I can persuade him :) Thanks guys.